# Using the IBM SBT database credential store with Oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, ibm-sbt

Has anyone used the database credential store com.ibm.sbt.security.credential.store.DBCredentialStore to store tokens for an OAuth2 endpoint. I am running a simple app on WebSphere 7 with a db2 database for the token storage. I have the managed bean for the store correctly configured in managed-beans.xml

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>CredStoreDB</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.ibm.sbt.security.credential.store.DBCredentialStore</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-property> 
        <property-name>jndiName</property-name> 
        <value>jdbc/sbtk</value> 
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property> 
        <property-name>tableName</property-name> 
        <value>SBTKREP</value> 
    </managed-property>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
    <!-- Fixed OAuth Application parameters -->
</managed-bean>
```

but the credentials never get stored to the database... no errors either. I can see in code that my endpoint is using the correct credentials store by doing...

```
pw.println("credential store is " + ((OAuth2Endpoint) ep).getCredentialStore());
```

What actually causes the credentials to be stored.. has anyone done this before? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: also, does your user, at the time of the request have a J2EE Principal?  I believe it is stored in the database based on that key

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the SBTKREP table exists in the database at jdbc/sbtk

If not, there are some scripts to run here:
https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/tree/master/samples/dbscripts